# How to save data from checkbox value to database using button

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to save data from checkbox to database

```
 Private Sub Check2_Click()
 If Check2.Value = True Then
  Check2.Caption = "OK"
  ElseIf Check2.Value = False Then
   Check2.Caption = "not ok"
  End If
 End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
   con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source 
   =C:\Users\MIS02\Documents\checkstrial.accdb;Persist Security Info = false"
   rs.Open "Select * from tableCheck", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
   DTPicker1.Value = Date
   End Sub

 Private Sub addBtn_Click()

  rs.AddNew
  rs.Fields("CheckItem").Value = Label2.Caption
  rs.Fields("Itemno").Value = Label17.Caption
  rs.Fields("Criteria").Value = Label38.Caption
  rs.Fields("AMafter").Value = Check2.Caption

  rs.Update
  MsgBox "Data add successfully"
```

The only fields that being saved in my database are labels
I want the output to be saved in database if the checkbox is checked "OK" and if not then "NOT OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Check2_Click`, use `vbChecked` instead of `True` and `vbUnchecked` instead of `False`.

You can also add an IIF statement when updating your record:

`rs.Fields("AMafter").Value = IIF(Check2.Value = vbChecked, "OK", "NOT OK")`

Comment: Glad to hear, please come back to Stack Overflow when you have programming questions. The `CheckBox.State` variable has other values than just `vbChecked` and `vbUnchecked`, it can also be `vbGrayed`. That is why it is not just True/False and why your original code doesn't work like it would with a RadioButton for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AMafter` field is defined as Boolean (Yes/No in Access), you need to set a Boolean value. Try the following:

`rs.Fields("AMafter").Value = (Check2.Value = vbChecked)`

Comment: it didn't save any data in my database sir

Comment: What's the data type for the `AMafter` field in your database?